# Show all rows when radio button selected

Tags: php, jquery, html

PHP generates an html table. In this table there are rows that should be shown
when a radio button in the parent row has been clicked. Strange thing is that only the first row is shown. But there are 4 rows of sub information. Here is a snippet:

PHP (sub info)

```
. "<tr class='info' style='display:none'><td id='e4' class='e4' colspan='2'>Subcell1</td><td class='e4' colspan='2'>Info 1:</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>EUR 310</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>free</td></tr>\n"
    . "</tr>\n"
```

. "Subcell1Info 2:not includednot includedEUR 230freenot includedfreefree\n"
        . "\n"

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#outbound tr input").click(function (){
               $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
               $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle();
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have given [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), that selects only one row... Instead, change it to [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), that selects all the elements appearing next.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#outbound tr input").click(function (){
       $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
       $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, now all rows are shown. However, when clicking a button in another parent row the previous sub rows are still being shown.

Answer (score 1):

You are only selecting one element with `next()`, you need to use the jQuery `nextAll()` method to select all of the other rows. Like so:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').toggle();
```